# Joining 2 Tables and selecting duplicate entries based on several columns

Tags: ms-access

I've got joined two tables and now I want to show all duplicate entries (and not the single on, but both) based on criterias in both tables.

Table1:

| Material_ID | Plant | Storage_old | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | GH65 | 5 |
| 1234 | 1 | ZG43 | 10 |
| 5436 | 1 | GH65 | 65 |

Table2:

| Plant | Storage_old | Storage_new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GH65 | ZT65 |
| 1 | ZG43 | ZT65 |
| 1 | GH65 | OE86 |

And I want the result of the select to be like this

| Material_ID | Plant | Storage_old | Storage_new | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | GH65 | ZT65 | 5 |
| 1234 | 1 | ZG43 | ZT65 | 10 |

I tried to use the select

```
    select
       t1.material_id,
       t1.plant_id   ,
       t1.storage_old,
       t2.storage_new,
       t1.stock
from
       t1
left join
       t2
on
       t1.plant        = t2.plant
and     t1.storage_old = t2.storage_old
group by
       t1.material_id,
       t1.plant_id   ,
       t2.storage_new
having
       count(*) > 1
```

with no success.
How do I use the group by without selecting all columns?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This query would fail even without the grouping. You show fields plant_id and plant - which is correct? Are the tables actually named t1 and t2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

Query1:

```
SELECT t1.plant, t2.storage_new, t1.material_id
FROM Table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON (t1.plant = t2.plant) AND (t1.storage_old = t2.storage_old)
GROUP BY t1.plant, t2.storage_new, t1.material_id
HAVING (((Count(*))>1));
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Table1.Material_ID, Table1.Plant, Table1.Storage_old, Query1.storage_new, Table1.Stock
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Query1 ON Table1.Material_ID = Query1.material_id;
```

Can nest SQL of Query1 within Query2 for an all-in-one statement.